# Converting 'ifconfig wlan0:avahi ...' command to use ip instead of ifconfig

Tags: networking, ifconfig, iproute, avahi, ad-hoc-network

I am currently working on setting up a wireless mesh network using [babeld](https://www.irif.fr/~jch%20/software/babel/) as the routing algorithm. The documentation is very sparse, and most of the configuration guides I've seen online are using the deprecated ifconfig command.

I could obviously just install `ifconfig` and run the commands as-is. But, if possible, I would prefer to not create an unnecessary dependency on `ifconfig`, and just use the built-in `iproute2`-based commands instead. So I have been converting `ifconfig` commands I'm coming across into their corresponding `ip` versions (e.g. `ifconfig eth0 up` --> `ip link set eth0 up`)

However, today I came across the following `babeld` [configuration script](http://reseaulibre.deuxpi.ca/configuration/babel/index.de.html#index2h1):

```
ifconfig wlan0 down
iwconfig wlan0 mode ad-hoc essid reseaulibre.ca ap 02:CA:FF:EE:BA:BE channel 9
ifconfig wlan0 up
avahi-autoipd wlan0
ifconfig wlan0:avahi netmask 255.255.255.255
babeld -D wlan0:avahi wlan0
```

... and I don't understand how to convert the following line into a corresponding `ip` command:

```
ifconfig wlan0:avahi netmask 255.255.255.255
```

**What is an equivalent command using `ip`, that would work in the context of the above configuration script?**

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be one thing there's no straight replacement for with `ip`.

One solution is:

```
IPNM=$(ip a sh dev wlan0:avahi scope global | awk  '/inet / {print $2}')
IP=${IPNM/\/*})
ip a add $IP/32 dev wlan0:avahi
ip a del $IPNM dev wlan0:avahi
```

This first extracts the IP address including netmask from the output of `ip addr show` and stores that in $IPNM. After that the subnet part is stripped and stored in $IP.

Now you can add the IP address with the desired netmask to the device, and then remove the old IP/netmask from the device.

Comment: Actually the equivalent of interface alias is the undocumented option `label` (as in `ip address show wlan0 label wlan0:avahi)`. But what doesn't seem possible is to add an IP which will have *both* `secondary` and `label` flags to do exactly (via netlink) what is doing ifconfig (via ioctl) and stay compatible with it. I suppose it's just a limitation of the ip command's syntax for a feature that isn't really useful.